# Can my Discord bot receive messages from anyone?

Tags: discord, permissions, bots

I'm writing a discord bot that gives out steam keys. I want people to be able to send it private messages, and I've coded it to respond to a single command via private messages, not from other bots. Then, it can check if this userID already got a key, respond privately with the steam key in a way that only one person can see, strike the key from the list, record the key and userID it went to, etc… So far, so good. **But I don't know what server/channel permissions to give @everyone, so they can successfully private message the bot to get a key.** I've googled the heck out of this. Writing the bot was easier than figuring this part out. Sigh. I don't have anyone to test this for me, either. (Don't hang on discord - lots of social anxiety - only one account…) Do any discord bot coders have the answer? I'm hoping this is an easy question, and I'm just stuck on it…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bot can receive messages from users whom it shares a server with.
Those users must also allow DMs.

Comment: Thank you. Will this still be true if the @everyone role is denied permission to message eachother in #general?

Comment: Yep, server permissions do not affect private messages.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to upvote, but I don't have enough 'reputation points' yet. Once I hit 15, you get an upvote. Cheers.

Comment: You can also accept the answer. There should be a "check" button next to it.

Comment: Yup. I can. How empowering! Thanks again!